# What is the correct syntax for pointer to a struct/class member

Tags: c++

First let me apologize if the question sounds vague.
Few years ago I saw a syntax which I can't recall. It allows me to create a pointer to a struct member.

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a member in my `DoComplexCalculation` class which points to a specific member in `SensorData` struct. To allow me to create many instances of the class where each instance work on different member of the struct (selected in the `Init` function).

The class

```
class DoComplexCalculation

    {
    public:
      void Init(std::string& which_member_to_work_on)
      {
         if (which_member_to_work_on == "Temperature")
            // initialize pointer to a Temperature struct member with, how ? 
         else if (which_member_to_work_on == "Humidity")
            // initialize pointer to a Humidity struct member with, how ?
      }
      void CalculateNow(const SensorData& sensorData)
      {
         int membertoworkon = // some syntax to select the member by the initialized pointer 
      }
     // Pointer to struct member, what is the syntax ?
    }
```

A struct with many integer members:

```
struct SensorData
{
  int Temperature;
  int Humidity;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer to class data member "::\*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/pointer-to-class-data-member)

Comment: Doing something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130612/sorting-function-for-a-vector-of-objects-based-on-different-fields/59130875#59130875) (Sorry for tooting my own horn).

Comment: This is all round bad design. First off, using strings to encode logic is an instance of [stringly typed code](https://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped), which is bad because it subverts the type system. Secondly, don’t have `Init` functions in your classes. Instead, use constructors — and initialise the object *fully*, never partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pointer on class member:

```
class DoComplexCalculation
{
    int SensorData::*memberPtr = nullptr;
public:
    void Init(const std::string& which_member_to_work_on)
    {
        if (which_member_to_work_on == "Temperature")
            memberPtr = &SensorData::Temperature;
        else if (which_member_to_work_on == "Humidity")
            memberPtr = &SensorData::Humidity;
         // ...
    }

    void CalculateNow(const SensorData& sensorData)
    {
         if (memberPtr == nullptr) { return; }         
         int membertoworkon = sensorData.*memberPtr;
         // ...
    }

};
```

Comment: If this list gets really long, and you don't mind the dynamic allocation, you may want to consider migrating your data into a map. Or, if static allocation is important, have all your `int`s in an array, and make an enum which "names" the indexes of the array.